# Using Nightwatch to Test Comments & Doctype

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I am an IT instructor and have begun utilizing Nightwatch to test students' homework to see if it is meeting specs.

I can test all the "normal" elements/attributes with no problem. My issue is on some stuff that you would probably not normally test in a production environment.

I want to test that they are using the correct HTML5 doctype, which lies outside of the root, of course, and I believe Nightwatch begins with the HTML node.

I also harp on them about using comments to make their own life and that of their fellow developer easier. So, I would like to test that they are leaving comments. Some parts of the comment are required and consistent, but other parts vary, such as their name within the comment. Here is a sample of a comment...

```
The Name of the Page
Sample Page for the Widgets
Author: your name
Date: the date
```

Again, I would probably not be testing for comments and doctype in the real world, but wonder if it is possible with Nightwatch?

I have tried the containsText() and text.to.contain() methods already with no success.

Any thoughts and guidance would be appreciated.

Also, I am not opposed to using another testing tool or any other middleware that might help if you know of any. I have not found any in my searching, nor have I found a solution to my quandary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that **Nightwatch** has not been designed to accomplish such a task. It is an amazing framework to perform acceptance testing on a GUI (Graphical User Interface), but it is not a web crawler. Browser automation is a resource-intensive operation, especially when you automate a real web browser via **Selenium WebDriver**. So if the code structure matters more than the graphical part, I would recommend you to use more "minimalistic" libraries like **CasperJS**. It is based on **PhantomJS**, a WebKit headless browser.

### Nightwatch

If you want to keep Nightwatch, the best thing you can do is using regular expressions with the `.source()` method which returns a serialization (string) of the DOM:

```
browser
  .url("http://www.website.com")
  .source(function (res) {
    if (/<!--/.test(res.value)) {
      console.log("Comment detected!");
    }
  })
```

This works to detect at least one comment, but you will not be able to check the `DOCTYPE` because it is not returned by the `.source()` method. Using XPath, the root element would be `/html`.

Moreover, here we use a basic `console.log` for comments, which is not ideal to perform a test. But the problem is that most Nightwatch assertion methods expect a CSS selector...

### Casper

This is much easier here...

With Casper, you can use the `.getHTML()` method to get a serialization of the DOM. But here, the `DOCTYPE` is returned and you can use assertions (`.assertMatch()`) to validate the result against regular expressions. Your code could have the following structure:

```
casper.test.begin('Test website', function (test) {
    casper.start('http://www.website.com', function () {
        var html = this.getHTML();
        test.assertMatch(html, /<!DOCTYPE html>/);
        test.assertMatch(html, /<!--.*-->/);
    });

    casper.then(function () {
        // Your code...
    });

    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

I have tested this code on a random page that contains a valid HTML5 document type declaration and some comments. It works fine.

Comment: Thanks. I had not heard of Casper. I am looking into that. In my cursory research, it appears that Nightmare is a wrapper around Casper, but also provides some functionality like Nightwatch. Have you used Nightmare? What are your thoughts?

Comment: From what I know, Nightmare has nothing to do with Casper. Nightmare is an alternative, not a wrapper. CasperJS is based on PhantomJS whereas Nightmare is based on Electron. I suggested Casper in my answer because this is the automation library I am the most familiar with, but there are many tools available. I have tested the most popular ones, including Zombie.js or WebdriverIO with CodeceptJS, but I always come back to Casper. Of course, this is just my opinion and you are free to use the tool you want. To make the right choice, you just have to wonder if you need to automate a GUI or not...